# Shown on time line vs Allowed on timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, development-environment

I am following the instructions posted on here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#define

It adds the item to my timeline, but I can only view it by going to Activity Log, once I hover over the button on the far right, its default selection is Allowed on Timeline, once I click Shown on Timeline, it appears.

Is there any way to default an application posting on someone's timeline to appear(shown on timeline) by default?

My site where I am using facebook application of Read an Article is [this](http://www.fresherpoint.com).

Comment: Please ref - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12360866/1628782

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just asked the same question today on Facebook’s developer group.  I had a response from a Facebook developer and he said you can’t force a timelime post to “Show on Timeline”.  Post will default to “Allowed on timeline”.  Apparently, to increase the chances of your story appearing on the timeline you need to post something that the user wants to see on their timeline!

See [this screen shot image](http://i60.tinypic.com/1e8m5c.png) for the actual response.

Update: I have found that setting the "fb:explicitly_shared" property to true is forcing it to appear on the timeline although the post is still set to "Allowed on timeline" not "Shown on timeline". I'm using the Facebook c# NuGet package and the following code worked fro me...

FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();

var postInfo = new Dictionary();

postInfo.Add("vip_bar",@"http://samples.ogp.me/252865028170797");

postInfo.Add("title", "The VIP Bar");

postInfo.Add("og:title", "The VIP Bar");

postInfo.Add("og:description", "Check me out getting leggless in the bar!");

postInfo.Add("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");

fb.PostTaskAsync(, (object)postInfo);